# Highest performance for finding substrings

Tags: java, string, search

I have an array of strings (keywords), and I need to check how many of those strings existing within a larger string (text read from file). I need the check to be case insensitive. 
At this moment what I do is this:

```
private void findKeywords() {
        String body = email.getMessage();
        for (String word : keywords) {
            if (body.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                //some actions                }
            if (email.getSubject().contains(word)) {
                //some actions
            }
        }
    }
```

From reading questions in here another solution came up:

```
private void findKeywords() {
        String body = email.getMessage();
        for (String word : keywords) {
            boolean body_match = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(word), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(body).find();
            boolean subject_match = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(word), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(email.getSubject()).find();
            if (body_match) {
                rating++;
            }
            if (subject_match) {
                rating++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which of these solutions is more efficient? Also is there another way to do this that is better? Any accepted solutions must be simple to implement(on par with the above) and preferably without external libraries as this is not very important issue in this case.

Comment: Why not try each and see which one runs the fastest???

Comment: Because then I wouldnt know if there is a solution even faster from the above.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Then why do you not ask if there is a faster solution?. By the way: there is. Use Lucene (or similar) to index your e-mails; indexed stores are much, much faster to search than raw strings.

Comment: My preference as a programmer would be the 1st code block as it's easier to spot what it's doing right away (and thus easier to modify).  Tuning an algorithm for better performance should only be done if it's really needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the solutions seem viable to me. One improvement I would suggest is moving functions out of the loop. In your current code you are repeatedly doing actions such as toLowerCase() and Pattern.compile which you only need to do once.

Obviously there are much faster methods to solve this problem, but they require much more complex code than these 5-liners.

Comment: Moving the `toLowerCase()` outside the loop has not just a performance advantage, it reduces some possibly huge string duplications.

Answer (score 1):

Better: build a single pattern with all keywords. Then search on that pattern. Assuming your keywords do not contain meta-characters (characters with special meanings in patterns), then use:

```
StringBuilder keywordRegex = new StringBuilder();
for (String w : keywords) {
   keywordRegex.append("|"+w);
}
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(keywordRegex.substring(1));
Matcher m = new p.matcher(textToMatch);
while (m.find()) {
    // match is at m.start(); word is m.group(0);
}
```

Much more efficient than iterating through all keywords: pattern compilation (once) will have generated an automata that looks for all keywords at once.

Comment: You'd need to escape each keyword for robustness, but this becomes progressively better the more keywords one has.

Answer (score 0):

I think the explicit regex solution you mentioned would be more efficient since it doesn't have the toLowerCase operation, which would copy the input string in memory and make chars lowercase.

Both solutions should be practical and your question is mostly academic, but I think the regexes provide cleaner code.

Comment: I think you are very mistaken about `String.contains()` using regex underneath. Which JDK are you talking about?

Comment: I was thinking of replaceAll

Answer (score 0):

If your email bodies are very large, writing a specialized case-insensitive contains may be justified, because you can avoid calling toUpperCase() on big strings:

```
static bool containsIgnoreCase(String big, String small) {
  if (small == null || big == null || small.length() > big.length()) {
    return false;
  }      
  String smallLC = small.toLowerCase();
  String smallUC = small.toUpperCase();
  for (int i = 0; i < big.length(); ++i) {
    if (matchesAt(big, i, smallLC, smallUC)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

private static bool matchesAt(String big, int index, String lc, String uc) {
  if (index + lc.length() > big.length()) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < lc.length(); ++i) {
    char c = big.charAt(i + index);
    if ((c != lc.charAt(i)) && (c != uc.charAt(i))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```